# "Property reference" of the class

Tags: c++builder

Is there a reference to a class property in C++Builder, analogous to a regular reference in C++? To understand what I mean, I will give the code (so far this is my solution to the problem):

```
    void change(TControl* object) {
      struct TAccessor : TControl { __property Text; };
      static_cast<TAccessor*>(object)->Text = L"some text";
    }
```

This function allows you to change the Text property of any object inherited from TControl.
But maybe there is a more elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: As a way of getting round the fact that TControl doesn't make the Text property accessible (derived classes that want Text property accessible must do this explicitly) I think this solution is quite elegant. But is this actually what you want to do? Strikes me as being a bit dangerous: there is probably a good reason why a designer hasn't made Text accessible....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach will update the `Text` of any `TControl`, even if it doesn't actually expose access to `Text` (which is declared `protected` in `TControl` itself, derived classes decide whether to promote it to `public`/`__published` as needed).

To account for that fact, you would have to use RTTI to discover if `Text` is accessible or not. You can also use RTTI to set the property value, without resorting to the `Accessor` trick.

For example, old-style RTTI (via the `<TypInfo.hpp>` header) works only with `__published` properties, nothing else, eg:

```cpp
#include <TypInfo.hpp>

void change(TControl* object) {
    if (IsPublishedProp(object, _D("Text"))
        SetStrProp(object, _D("Text"), _D("some text"));
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
#include <TypInfo.hpp>

void change(TControl* object) {
    PPropInfo prop = GetPropInfo(object, _D("Text"), TTypeKinds() << tkUString);
    if (prop)
        SetStrProp(object, prop, _D("some text"));
}
```

Whereas newer-style Extended RTTI (via the `<Rtti.hpp>` header) supports fields, methods, and properties, and all the supported member visibilities, eg:

```cpp
#include <Rtti.hpp>

typedef Set<TMemberVisibility, mvPrivate, mvPublished> TMemberVisibilitySet;

void change(TControl* object) {
    static const TMemberVisibilitySet WantedVisibilities = TMemberVisibilitySet() << mvPublic << mvPublished;
    TRttiContext ctx;
    TRttiType *type = ctx.GetType(object->ClassType());
    TRttiProperty* prop = type->GetProperty(_D("Text"));
    if ((prop) && (WantedVisibilities.Contains(prop->Visibility)) && (prop->IsWritable))
        prop->SetValue(object, _D("some text"));
}
```